# Error to integrate with QuickBooks

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm doing an integration with PHP my system, so I can launch sales in QuickBooks. To integrate'm using the API provided this link https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php.

Set everything as instructed, but the moment you throw a sale, I get the following error:

```
2020: [Required param missing, need to supply the required value for the API, Required parameter Line.DetailType is missing in the request]
```

The class that generates invoices is currently as follows:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/header.tpl.php';

?>

<pre>

    <?php

    $InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
    $Invoice        = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();

    $Invoice->setDocNumber('WEB' . mt_rand(0, 10000));
    $Invoice->setTxnDate('2015-12-10');

    $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
    $Line->setDetailType('Example');
    $Line->setAmount(12.95 * 2);
    $Line->setDescription('Example');

    $SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
    $SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
    $SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(12.95);
    $SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(2);

    $Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

    $Invoice->addLine($Line);

    $Invoice->setCustomerRef('67');

    if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realm, $Invoice))
    {
        print('Our new Invoice ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
    }
    else
    {        
        print($InvoiceService->lastError());
    }

    ?>

</pre>

<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/footer.tpl.php';
```

Someone has gone through this problem?

I really need help because they do not understand much about QuickBooks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This error:

`Required parameter Line.DetailType is missing in the request`

Means you are missing a required parameter named `Line.DetailType` in your request. More specifically -- in your case, you're actually sending an *invalid value* for this parameter.

```
$Line->setDetailType('Example');
```

That ^^^ is not valid. Please take the time to refer to Intuit's documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Invoice

And take the time to refer to the examples:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_add.php#L21

And notices that the documentation/examples show the correct value is:

```
// Set to SalesItemLineDetailfor this type of line.
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help.
I follow their advice.